# How to remove rows containing unique factor levels from a data frame in R?

Tags: r

I have a column called `Keywords`, and it is a factor data type with 150 levels. Most of these levels are combinations of other levels or typos. I'd like to remove all the rows whose `Keyword` is a level that only has 1-5 instances. How do I do that?

For instance:

Let's say I have 300 rows with 'a' as the keyword, a couple hundred 'b's and a few hundred 'c's. But then I have 100 other levels that should be one of those three, but are some variant like 'A 1' or 'A2'. I'm just trying to get an idea of the data, but all the relatively low-occuring levels are throwing off all the graphs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like

```
tt <- table(dd$Keywords)
rare_levels <- names(tt)[tt<5]
dd <- subset(dd,!Keywords %in% rare_levels)
```

You can use either `dd$Keywords <- factor(dd$Keywords)` or `dd$Keywords <- droplevels(dd$Keywords)` after subsetting to drop the rare factor levels from the list of levels (the *observations*, not the levels themselves, get dropped by `subset`)

Answer (score 4):

you can use `dplyr` package function `n()`

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
    mutate(cyl = as.factor(cyl)) %>% 
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    filter(n() >12)  # require each level with more than 12 obs
```

Comment: I'm getting a 404 during `install.packages("dplyr")` on R6: `Installing package into ‘.../R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘R6’ 
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/R6_2.1.3.zip'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL '...R6_2.1.3.zip': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  cannot open URL '...R6_2.1.3.zip'
...
package ‘dplyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked`